# Cross simplification property: does ax=ya $\Rightarrow$ x=y implies conmutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily unitary), we know that if R doesn't have zero divisors then it satisfies the cancellation laws: $\forall a,x,y \in R$ with $a \neq 0$ $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$ and similarly,  $xa=ya$ implies $x=y$ but $xa=ay$ does not imply $x=y$

It is clear that this implication is true if $R$ is conmutative, so then I thought if the converse is true, but I could't either prove it nor disprove it.

So the exact statement is:
is a ring $R$ without zero divisors and for which $ax=ya$ hapens only when $x=y$ or $a=0$ necessarily commutative?
Can you prove this or give a couterexample ring?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean to say *ring* in the first clause?

Comment: Please search before posing questions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x,a \not= 0$ then $a(xa) = (ax)a \implies xa = ax$ then is a commutative ring